# Is it okay to use emphatic "do" right before "am"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to use emphatic "do" right before "am" or is it a nonsense in English?

Does this text, for example, sound unnatural in English?

> In my posting here I am not trying to be on Beth's or on Jack's side,
> but what I ***do*** am trying is to stay objective.

Comment: No. ... but what I **am** trying to do is stay objective.

Comment: ...or *No, but what I **do** try to do is [to] stay objective.* Or even *No, but what I **do** is try to stay objective.* Personally though I wouldn't bother - the "explicit emphasis" serves no real purpose, and isn't easily conveyed orthographically anyway.

Comment: \**It do be like that sometimes*, but in general emphatic *do* doesn't go together with auxiliary verbs. I think your construction ("but what I am trying to do is to stay objective") is already empathic enough over the usual "but I'm trying to stay objective").

Comment: @MaciejStachowski "It do be like that" is an AAVE construction, and is not correct whatsoever in standard English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not standard usage.  If you wanted to emphasize, you could word it as

> In my posting here I am not trying to be on Beth's or on Jack's side. What I am trying to do is to stay objective.

Notice how you the second sentence mirrors the phrasing in your first sentence.  "I am not trying to"/"I am trying to.."

Answer (score 0):

When used to emphasise the following verb, "do" is an auxiliary verb.

"Do" cannot be followed by any other auxiliary.  You can't have "do must", "do will", "do might", etc.  Nor can you have "do have" if "have" is an auxiliary - for example, you couldn't say "I do have taken".  But if you're using "have" as a full verb, you can say "do have" - e.g. "I do have a good idea".

Informally, "do" can be followed by the semi-modals "used to" and "ought to".  In this case it is always past tense ("did ought to", "did used to").  This also results in informal negations "didn't ought to", etc, which coexist with "ought not to", etc.

"Be" can't follow "do" (in standard English).  "Do" is always followed by a bare *infinitive*, so if it were possible to follow "do" with "be", we would say "I do be", "she does be", etc - not "I do am".  However, it is non-standard to follow "do" with "be".